# Is this code safe from SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to make my code as safe as possible from any type of attack I was hoping for some insight on the simple code I am using below. Any pointers on how to make it safer if it is vulnerable and why would be awesome. I have read that using prepared statements is the best practice to safeguard against attacks.

```
<?php 

    try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'XXXXX');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO people (name, email) VALUES (:name, :email)');

    $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'], ':email' => $_POST['email']));

    #If one or more rows were returned...

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo "Added $_POST[name] with email $_POST[email] succsessfully";
    $conn = null;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're safe from SQL injection, but you now have issues with XSS in your echo. Make sure you always sanitize / escape user input before its echo'd.

```
echo "Added $_POST[name] with email $_POST[email] succsessfully";
```

should become

```
echo "Added" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) . "with email" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) . "succsessfully";
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the example I tried this out and it worked but can I use a function/filter that keeps the <p>,etc... tags from getting added to DB to keep it readable

Comment: Of course, but make sure you do any replacement or sanitization that you would like to do before you bind them to the prepared statement.

Comment: Consider using HTML Purifier for prevention of XSS . It is very effective however there are performance hits .

Answer (score 5):

It is SQL injection safe because of the prepared statement. But keep in mind that echoing those variables in your browser can cause XSS problems. 
Best is to always make sure your user input is clean, usually htmlspecialchars is sufficient for outputting, better is when you clean your user input before submitting it to your database.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the use of parameters in the SQL query reduces the posibility of a SQL injection attack.
But i would clean the data received from POST, also check if that exists.

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) : NULL;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) : NULL;
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':email' => $email));
```

Keep in mind that if you pass null, those database fields should accept null values

Comment: Just a point. Its better to store raw data in the database and sanitize when you output it.

Comment: Never thought it before, why? Is it quicker or to avoid losing data?

Answer (score 1):

I would also consider using [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) out of habit .. my understanding is that PDO will do a type check (not that it matters for PARAM_STR), which might save you from some other attack vectors.

(and add in the XSS sanitizing Skatox, Ryan, and John mention.)

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) : NULL;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) : NULL;
stmt = bindParam(':name',$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
stmt = bindParam(':email',$email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```